# Get the network transforming data bytes and save them

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, network-programming, data-transfer

I have an application and I want to save or log the network transforming data bytes. But I have no Idea how to do that. Does anybody know how can I do that?? (It's not for steal data! I just want my network transforming data bytes)

Comment: "network transforming data bytes" ?

Comment: I'm not sure a language barrier is an appropriate reason for a downvote, but I also wonder what "network transforming data bytes" means.  Are you trying to write a sniffer?

Comment: @DavidStratton: yes but for mine network!

Comment: @DavidStratton: I didn't know the name and I couldn't say it better!

Comment: @ahmadali Can you comment what you mean by "network transforming bytes" in Persian so we can try our hand at translating it?

Comment: @ChristopherPfohl اطلاعاتی که از طریق شبکه منتقل می شود را در جایی ذخیره کنم

Comment: K, Google Translate gives us: "Information that is transmitted through the network in place to save"  @Ahmadali, are you just trying to log all your home network traffic?  The only part I dont' understand is "In Place" (را در جایی)

Comment: I think that ahmadali just wants to detect everything that transmits over his network. I mean he wants to save every bytes that are transmitting over his local network.

Comment: @ChristopherPfohl: google translate isn't a good persian to english translator!

Comment: @ahmadalishafiee I know google translate is a bad translator (for pretty much everything), but it often gives a different slant on things that's very helpful.  Especially if you know the types of errors it typically makes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually I just needed the `Sniffer` name that I get it from the second comment of the question by David Stratton. I searched google and found [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/17031/A-Network-Sniffer-in-C) and it's more simple than [this](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/fyratkocak/PacketSniffer12032005034955AM/PacketSniffer.aspx)!(because I wanted a simple code) and I could get the package as byte data with some code changing. thanks everyone to help me!

Answer (score 3):

If I am reading properly, I think you want to write a [Packet Sniffer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Packet_analyzer).  There's a downloadable source code for one [here](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/fyratkocak/PacketSniffer12032005034955AM/PacketSniffer.aspx) , which you should be able to modify.